# Очередность http-заголовоков

Tags: http

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в http какая то жесткая очередность http-загловков?

Я имею ввиду следующее, для примера, ответ от сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 07 Aug 2021 16:33:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 166
Connection: close
```

Не будет ли нарушением http прокола, если севера пришел ответа в таком порядке:

```
Content-Length: 166
Content-Type: text/html
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 07 Aug 2021 16:33:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: nginx
```

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` это не заголовок и оно обязано быть всегда в начале

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC2616 (4.2 Message Headers)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2) говорит:

> The order in which header fields with differing field names are
> received is not significant. However, it is "good practice" to send
> general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-
> header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

То есть, порядок не имеет значения, но есть "good practice": сперва основные  заголовки, потом заголовки запроса, заголовки ответа и последние заголовки сущности

Исключением являются повторяющиеся заголовки (об этом по ссылке [RFC2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.2))